# PrettyUrl from some string like (Áccent, - () #$%someText&/) Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pretty-urls

Is there any existing library or code for ASP.NET MVC that can transform some string into a pretty url much like stackoverflow does with questions ?

Having the string:

> Hello there! This is some weird with accénted words and funcky - / Characters (29)

to something like:

> Hello-there-This-is-some-weird-accented-words-and-funcky-Characters-29

Comment: I guess there are a lot of things to take into cosideration for a simple replace. like é to e, and not having lots of --- because of string transformation and some etc I do not imagine beforehand. Take a look at the string generated from the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, removing diacritics has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net).

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(string text) 
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in normalizedString)
    {
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

If you take `RemoveDiacritics`, then all you need to do is some Regex replace, replacing all non-alpha numeric characters with a single dash.

```
public static string PrettyUrl(string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(RemoveDiacritics(s), "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-").Trim('-');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hdOXdX)